# Rectangle class java.lang.Object

Tags: java

Can someone please explain to me the difference or benefits rather to using the rectangle class

```
ex. Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
```

versus the graphics class drawRec method?

```
g.drawRec(x,y,w,h);
```

I'm thinking that you can create a new object outside of paint() or paintcomponent() which gives creating an object more options and maybe the associated methods is a bonus?  I'm just speculating though because the tutorial I was going through switched from using one to the other without explaining why.  I believe I understand how to use them just not when it's better to use which. Please try to keep your responses at the beginner level seeing as how I'm just starting out but of course any assistance is GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks!!

Here is a code segment of what I'm working with:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    g.drawImage(yellowBall, xCoor, yCoor, this);
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle((boardXSize/2), (boardYSize/2),50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y,r1.width, r1.height);

    repaint();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use instances of Rectangle when you have to manage them for some reason (e.g. in a drawing program or some kind of window or layout management). There is hardly a good reason to create them solely for calling Graphics.fillRect, as in your example.

Comment: ok awesome. Thanks for clarifying. I was thinking that but wasn't sure because the tutorial didn't explicitly state it.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is look at the [JavaDocs for Rectangle.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) If you want any of these abilities, use a Rectangle.

Also, as @user281377 notes, a single Rectangle object is easier to manage, store in a List, persist, etc. than four ints.